# Adding Components From ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to add Components From Backing Bean.I'm having String in Managed Bean which will have all jsf components as a String.In UI i need to render as a component.
My Managed bean Coding is

```
String htmlContent = "<h:inputText/>";

public String getHtmlContent()
{
   return this.htmlContent;
}
```

and XHTML coding is

```
<h:outputText value="#{managedBean.htmlContent}" escape = "false"/>
```

If I use Html tags in htmlContent like

```
String htmlContent = "<input type='text'/>;
```

My Logic will works fine.if i use jsf tags in that String ,the JSF components render as it is.It will not render as Html.

I know at the end all the Jsf tags will be converted into html tags.
Is there is any way to handle dynamic rendering of jsf tags other than ui:composition and ui:include ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: try remove escape="false"

Comment: It could not work for me..

Comment: Try assigning the `rendered` attribute with dynamic value form server side to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your solution is a bad idea. As I understand you want to generate piece of your view in backing bean. Don't try to mix your models/controllers with view. Instead of this just add data to your view in `<h:panelGroup/>` and add `rendered` tag so you can control if it will be rendered or not.

I will do it in this way:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean {
    private boolean renderPieceOfView;
    // getter and setter for renderPieceOfView
}
```

view

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBackingBean.renderPieceOfView}">
    ... this will be rendered or not ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Also you can create template files which will be placed in `... this will be rendered or not ...`

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBackingBean.renderPieceOfView}">
    <ui:include src="#{templateFactory.currentViewPath}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: It will be better a `@ViewScoped` managed bean. See [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: As a web developer i know MVC Pattern.But I want to know is it possible in Jsf  ?

Comment: I don't think so that it is possible to change *.xhtml content from managedBean. I'm not experienced JSF developer and I can be wrong.

Comment: @VijayKumar yes it is possible but as you know from MVC it's not really good to have view logic in business logic components like having a `String` with HTML content. Using `rendered` attribute and/or Facelets tags as `<ui:composition>`, `<ui:fragment>`, `<ui:ignore>` (and more) are the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your Response.I know its not good.but in my situation i need to do

Comment: @VijayKumar then it would be better to ask about your current functional requirement instead of asking *can I do this bad practice*? Please edit the question and **add** the relevant info of your real problem and please **do not delete** none of its actual content (otherwise this answer would lost its meaning).